# Clear state when TextInput text is cleared

Tags: react-native, textinput

I am trying to clear a string I have previously set to state when I clear textInput. I have tried below code but it's not clearing the string in the state. What am I doing wrong, pleas?

```
<TextInput
    ref={(el) => this.myInput = el}
    onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
    text={this.state.mytext}
    placeholder='Enter Text'
    placeholderTextColor='#999'
    keyboardType='numeric'
    returnKeyType='next'
/>

onChangeText = (t) => {
    this.props.setData('mytext', t)
    if(t == ''){
        this.setState({
            newText: ''
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the `value` property to `TextInput`. In your case the `TextInput` doesn't know which value to look for.

```
 <TextInput
     value={this.state.yourValue}
     onChangeText={yourValue => this.setState({ yourValue }) }
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm the issue is I guess with the prop. Not quite sure if there's a prop called `text` in `TextInput`.
Also if might want to use the setState for on change without the check.

```
<TextInput
    ref={(el) => this.myInput = el}
    onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
    value={this.state.mytext}
    placeholder='Enter Text'
    placeholderTextColor='#999'
    keyboardType='numeric'
    returnKeyType='next'
/>

onChangeText = (t) => {
    this.props.setData('mytext', t);
    this.setState({
       newText: t
    });
}
```